# RxJS how to use combineLatest with startWith with multiple values?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a question about using `combineLatest` with the `startWith` operator

The code below works

```js
const data_1$ = new Subject<string>();
const data_2$ = new Subject<number>();

viewModel$ = combineLatest([data_1$, data_2$])
   .pipe(map([data_1, data_2]) => {
      return { data_1, data_2 };
   })
```

however now if I want to use `startWith` operator

```js
const data_1$ = new Subject<string>();
const data_2$ = new Subject<number>();

viewModel$ = combineLatest([data_1$, data_2$])
   .pipe(
      startWith(["hello", 1]),
      map([data_1, data_2]) => {
         return { data_1, data_2 };
      })
```

The `map` part will infer that `data_1` and `data_2` can be `string | number`.
Can I get it to infer as the first example which doesn't use `startWith`? I know about `BehaviorSubject` and it could be used instead of `startWith` but in my case I need to use startWith.

Comment: Maybe `startWith(["hello", 1] as const)`? You need to get it to be `[string, number]` not `(string | number)[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from the [official documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/startWith), `startWith`'s typing is given by:

```js
startWith<T, D>(...values: D[]): OperatorFunction<T, T | D>
```

In your case, you want to ensure that `startWith` only returns something of the type `[string, number]`.

The issue occurs because when you provide the array with `['hello',1]` it considers the type as `(string|number)[]`. This is because in the generic declaration, only one type, `D[]` is provided. Hence why it considers the type of `['hello',1]` to be `(string|number)[]`, which fits `D[]`.

To solve this, you can provide the typing explicitly with the use of the generic:

```js
startWith<[string, number]>(['hello', 1])
```

The question then arises, why does map infer the argument type currently?
Well the answer to this is also in the [official typing of map](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/map):

```js
map<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => R, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<T, R>
```

In `map`'s case, it infers the type from the the provided value `T`. Since there is no need to match any array casting, the value of `[string, number]` is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to declare the argument passed to the *startWith* operator with **as const**.

```
combineLatest([data_1$, data_2$]).pipe(
 startWith(['hello', 1] as const),
 map(([data_1, data_2]) => (return { data_1, data_2 }))
);
```

The expression **as const** makes the compiler treat the array as a readonly tuple.  That's actually too specific for what you want to use in the *map* operator.  However, the *startWith* operator won't return that tuple type, as it returns the union of the type of the argument and the type passed along the stream.  That return type ends up being [string, number] - which is what you want.